# Mond und Licht ist vor Schmerzen untergangen

Tags: grammaticality

I read in the duet "[So ist mein Jesus nun gefangen](https://www.vmii.org/bwv-244-matthaeus-passion/27a-so-ist-mein-jesus-nun-gefangen)" from Bach's Matthäuspassion the following sentence :

*Mond und Licht*

*Ist vor Schmerzen untergangen,*

that I fail to understand grammatically. I would have rather expected *sind vor Schmerzen untergegangen* but that would have caused rythm problems -- hear the text [here](https://youtu.be/zvM32cKDaSk?t=82). (The *sind* doesn't change the rythmn but the supplementary *ge* from *untergegangen* does.)

Is this the only reason or is there a grammatical rule that I miss or maybe even an old german grammatical rule ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lyrics, of course, enjoy a certain amount of liberty from the hard rules of grammar, and the proper past participle would not have fit the notes of the music. That's very probably the main reason for the omission.

The other thing, however, is, that very many upper German dialects  (thus, mainly in the southern half) tend to omit the "ge-" in the past participle completely or shorten it to a "g'-" (swallow the vocal). Saxon, Bach's mother tongue, is one of them (actually, the border for that phenomenom divides Saxony pretty much in half) and Picander (Bach's text author) was born in the Osterzgebirge, whose dialect does exactly that. Further south, the "ge-" is generally omitted, so

*Ich bin gegangen* mutates to *I bin gangn* in bavarian, or *I be ganga* in Swabian, *Ich habe gegessen* would be *I hab gessn* or *I han gessa*.

So, there is at least *some* foundation in German dialects for this omission.

To answer the second part of the question (why the phrase is in singular): *Mond* und *Licht* is the same here - the moon was the only light source, so, you could argue the phrase is more like "Mond und [damit] Licht ist untergegangen".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the conjugation of "sein" - I would say say that the lyric is kind of saying "The moon has set from sorrow, and therefore also the light is gone"  or "Mond (und daher auch Licht) ist unter(ge)gangen". Hence the singular conjugation.

Comment: This is not what the lyrics are saying. *Mond und Licht ist vor Schmerzen untergangen, Weil mein Jesus ist gefangen.* Moon and Light are drowned into pain, for my Jesus is captured.